# How to fill ellipses with different colors using GraphicsPath in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing, drawing2d

To solve flickering problem in WinForms when drawing multiple shapes, I decided to use `GraphicsPath`do draw all shapes and then render using `Graphics`. It works perfectly; drawing never flickers even if a high number of shapes are drawn.

```
 panel.Paint += (sender, args) => {
      var graphicsPath = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Winding);

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
          graphicsPath.AddEllipse(0, i * 5, 20, 20);
      }

      args.Graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(Color.Red),  graphicsPath);
```

However, in this case all ellipses are the same color. Drawing every ellipse using `graphics.FillPath()` also causes flickering when shapes are redrawn (fot instance on Paint event).

Is there a way to draw each shape with a different color while continuing bulk drawing such as above one?

Comment: `form.CreateGraphics();` Usually wrong. Use the `Paint` event and its `e.Graphics` object to draw persistent graphics.. Also: Do set `Form.DoubleBuffered = true`to prevent flicker.! Then maybe your code will work, but as we see only so little it is hard to tell. Do fix these issues first! - Of course __one__ `GraphicsPath` can only have __one__ color or maybe several if you fill it with e.g. a `LinearGradientBrush`..

Comment: @TaW I am actually doing that. I just forgot when I was trying to simplify the example. Thank you.

Comment: OK, that looks different. But what is the question? One Path, one Brush, no way around this. And no need with DoubleDuffering no flicker will happen. What control do you draw on?

Comment: **And no need with DoubleDuffering no flicker will happen** what do you mean by that?

Comment: `DoubleBuffered` is a property some Controls expose (Form) or have already on (PictureBox). Most others can be tweaked to turn it on too. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185298/update-datagridview-very-frequently/44188565#44188565) for an example code..

Comment: [Using Nested Graphics Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-nested-graphics-containers). You can also manage a `List<GraphicsPath>`. But it would be better to have specialized classed (possibly derived from a common abstract class/interface) that describe each shape, which can then be added to a GraphicsPath. The Double Buffering feature is relevant here.

Comment: @Jimi: While very interesting I don't see how that link is relevant here. He wants to break up the path elements he had only lumped together to avoid flicker which only happend because he didn't know about buffering..

Comment: @TaW  I pushed the Enter key before completing the comment :)

Comment: hehe, my fault I read too fast ;-)