# WinForms Flickering after Maximizing - Double Buffering

Tags: c#, winforms, double-buffering

I have a "Master" form with navigation buttons on the left side, and a panel on the right that I use as a holder for child forms. It's pretty simple but the code for this is below.

```
public void showForm(Form form)
{
    // Disposed Prior Form & Load New
    form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    form.TopLevel = false;
    pnlMain.Controls.Clear();
    pnlMain.Controls.Add(form);
    form.Show();
}
```

The Main issue I'm having is that everything works fine, I get virtually no flicker using the code below when navigating from form to form, but as soon as I maximize my "Master" form (which in turn enlarges the "Child" form)... even if I un-maximize and go back to the original size it starts flickering like crazy when I navigate to a new form. It's as if after maximizing it completely disregards the code put in place to fix the flickering in the first place. I should also mention that the "Child" Form has it's own form draw event which is why I have these things in place to reduce the flickering, it's normally not an issue until maximized.

```
public void drawBackgroundChild(PaintEventArgs e, Form form)
{
   // prevents error on resize
   if (form.ClientRectangle.Width == 0 || form.ClientRectangle.Height == 0)
       return;

   using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(form.ClientRectangle,
                                                                     UserSettings.secondaryColor1,
                                                                      UserSettings.secondaryColor2,
                                                                      90F))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, form.ClientRectangle);
            }
}



protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        var cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;    // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
        return cp;
    }
}
```

I have tried the code above as well as the code below multiple times on the "Master" and "Child" Forms. Tested it out a bunch of different ways but no luck. Does anyone know if resizing the Windows Form disables Double Buffering or something to this extent?

```
 DoubleBuffered = true;
 this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
```

Comment: a) what flickers? The form or the panel? b) try to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185298/update-datagridview-very-frequently/44188565#44188565) code to turn db on! c) no, resizing will certainly not turn db on or off.

Comment: @TaW The "Child" form inside the panel is what begins to flicker... I forgot to mention that this form inside the panel also has Paint Event, I'll update the post.

Comment: @TaW DoubleBuffered is enabled for all forms being used and is not an issue until resized. The only thing that I can think of is that the panel holder for the "Child" forms does not have double buffered specifically enabled for that control, and that somehow resizing affects it but idk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to remove any sort of double buffering / createparams etc. from the master form, and put it exclusively into the child forms....

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
       {
         var cp = base.CreateParams;
         cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;    // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
         return cp;
       }
}


frmChild()
{
    ResizeRedraw = true;
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                  ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
}
```