# How to filter DataGridView to keep only a given set of rows

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

In `C#` I have `DataGridView` populated via `DataSource`. With some custom made filter I determine a subset of rows (by looping through the rows and checking the conditions on columns, to be precise) and need to keep/show only these rows in the DatGridView.

One option I understand is to loop through the grid and hide the rows which are outside my index set. This, however, is painfully slow for larger set of rows. 
My question is:

> given a datagridview which is bind to a datasource, and a subset of its rows, is there an efficient way to keep only those rows in datagridview?

Comment: Slow speed probably comes only from the GUI updates. You may want to Suspend/ResumeLayout those or [DoubleBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185298/update-datagridview-very-frequently/44188565#44188565) the DGV. - Or you could add an indicator/filter column in the query, which you set in code and can then set/unset in a Filter string.

Answer (score 1):

Slow speed probably comes only from the GUI updates. You may want to

- [Suspend/ResumeLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout?view=netframework-4.8) the DGV and/or
- [DoubleBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185298/update-datagridview-very-frequently/44188565#44188565) the DGV.

The latter will speed up all display operations including scrolling.

---

- If you'd rather go for a real filter you will need an extra column to hold the filter value and a `BindingSource`.

(You won't need the extra colum, if you can put your logic into the filter..)

Assuming a `DataTable DT` as your `DataSource` first add a filter column:

```
DT.Columns.Add("Filter", typeof(int));
```

Next create a  `BindingSource BS = new BindingSource();`

Now bind the original datasource to the bindingsource and use it as the new datasource:

```
BS.DataSource = DT;
yourDGV.DataSource  = BS;
```

Now you can use your code to set a value for the filter column and finally set or unset the filter:

```
BS.Filter = "Filter = 23";  // use your indicator logic!
BS.Filter = "";              // unset filter
```

For the Filter you can use the DataColumn.Expression Property [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8).

- If you want to see the filter column you need to add it to the DGV columns as well and set the connection to the datasource.

Example:

```
yourDGV.Columns.Add("Filter", "filter");
yourDGV.Columns["Filter"].DataPropertyName = "Filter";
```

Comment: thanks for your comments. I've actually tried the `DoubleBuffer` option, but with no success. There are ~24000 rows in my example, and for the test I loop over rows hiding every row with even index. This takes around **47** secs. What is interesting, no apparent flickering of the control or UI happens. Then, I tried to do the same with the entire grid hidden setting `visible = false`, took **5** secs. Bringing the hidden grid into view took another ~30 secs. I'll try with the rest of your suggestions, and see if I can get any improvement.

Answer (score 0):

How about you fill the Dgv from a code.  Write a Select Statement to populate a DataTable then,  proceed to setting the Datatable as DS for your datagridview then finally if you need to filter just call the querying method then it will call others aswell.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but what do you mean by `call the querying method` ?  The query, in my case, cannot be transformed into simple select statements.

Comment: Unfortunately u have to have a Database Reading Method i.e.

Comment: public datatable readsql(quey){

put all your query here 

write all query result into a DataTable

return DataTable; 
}

Comment: @ShyamVemula,  I don't see how my code will help with answering the question. DataBinding was made in design mode, just by adding a datasource, and the filtering, as I said is via a loop over the grid, checking the query (conditions on each column) created by a user. It has no SQL as such.

Comment: Try doing it Programatically i can help

Comment: Ho do you filter by text?
I tired to add a string Filter column but with,e.g:
            BS.Filter = "Filter = rem";
but that did not work