# How to dynamically filter DataGridView using TextBox data?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I created a simple DataGridViewa with a single column and added a TextBox above.
Currently the text actually a DataTable (I though this would make things easier for filtering) with 2 columns, number and text (I hide the number in the DataGridView ). I can change it to any other class if required.

When the user enters a letter in the TextBox, I want to dynamically filter and show only the lines containing this text.

I load the data to the DataGridView like this:

```
private void PhrasesForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    phrasesDataGridView.ReadOnly = true;
    phrasesDataGridView.DataSource = _phrases.Phrases;
    phrasesDataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    this.phrasesDataGridView.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
}
```

When add another letter the filter will be readjusted.
What do I write here...

```
private void filterBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

[image: this]

Comment: [Filter DataGridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56355044/how-to-filter-datagridview-to-keep-only-a-given-set-of-rows/56356995?r=SearchResults&s=1|57.8788#56356995)

Comment: I suggest to Check out ObjectListView component.  You can do things like this so much easier.  http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use textbox to search data in data grid view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809201/how-to-use-textbox-to-search-data-in-data-grid-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a DataGridView, or any Control with a `DataSource`, consider using [Nuget Package BindingListView](https://github.com/waynebloss/BindingListView). It has functionality to sort the binding list by any column on a mouse click, but it also has functionality to filter the data.

```
List<Customer> customers = ...
BindingListView<Customer> customerView = new BindingListView<Customer>(customers);
dataGridView1.DataSource = customerView;
```

And presto, if shows all Customers. The columns depend on you column definition.

To filter the customers, for instance, show only customers with born before a certain date:

```
void ShowCustomers(DateTime limitDate)
{
    customerView.ApplyFilter( customer => customer.BirthDay < limitDate));
}
```

Result: only the older Customers are shown.

You can do it similarly:

```
void ShowItemsWithPhraseStart(string phraseStart)
{
    myView.ApplyFilter(row => row.Phrase.StartsWith(phraseStart));
}
```

And bingo: the datagrid shows only the row with a value for property Phrase that starts with phraseStart.

```
private void OnTextBocChanged(object sender, ...)
{
    var text = this.TextBox1.Text;
    ShowItemsWithPhraseStart(text);
}
```