# DataGridView - Assigning DefaultCellStyle for each row run extremely slow

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcellstyle

I have a DataGridView bound to a DataTable with 5000 rows, 36 columns and I'd like to change the cell style of each row based on its content, but the function I made take an insanely long time to run (100 rows every 5 min).

This is my function:

```
private void formatRows()
{
      DataGridViewCellStyle GroupCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
      DataGridViewCellStyle SubTotCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();

      GroupCellStyle.Font = new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
      GroupCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(235, 235, 235);
      SubTotCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(155, 155, 255);

      dataGridView1.SuspendLayout();
      for (int r = 0; r < dbInterface.ds.Tables["articles"].Rows.Count; r++)
      {
            if (dbInterface.ds.Tables["articles"].Rows[r].Field<short>("FLGGroup") == 2)
                  dataGridView1.Rows[r].DefaultCellStyle = GroupCellStyle;

            else if (dbInterface.ds.Tables["articles"].Rows[r].Field<short>("FLGGroup") == 0)
                  dataGridView1.Rows[r].DefaultCellStyle = SubTotCellStyle;
      }
      dataGridView1.ResumeLayout();
}
```

I can't figure out why it take so much time. Is that normal with DataGridView?

Comment: Hm. Maybe [doublebuffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185298/update-datagridview-very-frequently/44188565#44188565) will help? Just a guess..

Comment: How often do you call this `formatRows` method? Changing designer properties during rendering will be extremely slow, indeed. If this is called during rendering I suggest to use `CellPainting` event instead where you can access the style (or even better, the `Graphics`) for the cell.

Comment: And don't reevaluate `dbInterface.ds.Tables["articles"].Rows` three times in each iterations. Store the value before the loop.

Comment: Nitpicking: Let's make it:  _**up to** three times_ and: _store the **reference**_ - But it really shouldn't take __that__ long in any case.. - This is not normal and I suspect that something else is going on. Did you code other events that might be triggered?

Comment: Usually, the [DataGridView.CellFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting) event (or similar - as RowPrePaint/PostPaint etc. - depending on what needs to be adjusted) is used to adjust/refine the rows/cells aspect. So the code is called when needed and you don't have to format the whole content if the DataGridView each time, possibly causing cascading effect, if you have other *refinements* in place. It's not clear when `formatRows()` is called.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I found what it is. I had  a `dataGridView1.Columns[c].AutoSizeMode=AllCells` in another method (formatColumns) wich I call before formatRows (I call both them once). This setting drammatically drop down the performaces and should be avoided in this case. Thank's for yor suggestion.

Comment: creating new objects in a loop should always be avoided, better create them outside the loop and re-use