# Setting the height of Rows of a DataGridView to a custom value is slow

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, row-height

I'm working on a WinForms project, I have a Form with 5 data-bound DataGridView Controls.
I need to set a custom height to each Row:

[image]

I use the following code:

```
private void dgv_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
     dgv.SuspendLayout();
     var rowHeight = CalculateRowHeight((MyDto)dgvBatches.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem));
     dgvBatches.Rows[e.RowIndex].Height = rowHeight;
     dgvBatches.ResumeLayout();
}
```

It works but the DataGridView loading and scrolling is slow.
Is there any tricks to improve loading and scrolling speed?

Comment: You ca try to [doublebuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185298/update-datagridview-very-frequently/44188565#44188565) the dgv.. Also: Are you sure you need to set the row hights do often?

Comment: @TaW I used `doublebuffer` too, yes each row height depend on row data.

Comment: _each row height depends on row data_ sure, we can see that but adapting the row height should only be necessary when the hieght/data actually do change. Log out the event calls to see how often it happens now!

Comment: @TaW How can I Log out event calls?

Comment: Insert a Console.Writeline into the dgv_RowPrePaint event

Comment: So, my question(s) is “WHAT” determines a rows height? What is `CalculateRowHeight` doing? What would “change” a rows height once it has been set? I question why you did not post the `CalculateRowHeight` code in the first place? This code is obviously relevant.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks, your suggestions solved the problem, please post your suggestions as answer.

Comment: @JohnG `MyDto` has a `Weight` property and The height of each row depends on the weight of `MyDto.Weight`. you are right, My mistake was to change the height every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RowPrePaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint) event is raised constantly: each time you scroll the DataGridView (multiple times), click on a Cell (2 or more times: 1 for the Header), when you hover the Mouse Pointer over 1 or more Cells, when you change a value etc.
It appears that the calculation of the Rows' height is only needed when a source of data is assigned to the Control, my suggestion is to perform this operation when data binding is complete.

The Control notifies that the binding is complete, raising the [DataBindingComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete) event.
In its handler, you can then suspend the layout, perform the calculations needed and assign the result to the each Row added to the grid:

```
private void dgv_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.Reset) {
        dgvBatches.SuspendLayout();
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvBatches.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {
            if (i == dgvBatches.NewRowIndex) continue;
            var rowHeight = CalculateRowHeight((MyDto)dgvBatches.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem));
            dgvBatches.Rows[e.RowIndex].Height = rowHeight;
        }
        dgvBatches.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
    else if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged) {
        // Partner with CellValueChanged
    }
}
```

The `DataBindingComplete` event lets you know what caused the binding notification.
When you first assign a value to the `DataSource` property, the `e.ListChangedType` member will be set to [`ListChangedType.Reset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.listchangedtype), when a `DataBoundItem` value changes, it will be `ListChangedType.ItemChanged`, so you can determine what action is needed in this context.
You probably don't need to recalculate everything if a single Cell value changes, if it can be changed at all.
In case it does, you can resize a single Row, or all Rows that follow the Current, etc.

Since this layout may become complex, you could also benefit from double-buffering your DataGridView, unless you have a *high number* <sup>1</sup> of Rows (it doesn't look like, but it could be).

Try to add this to the Form Constructor, see whether it's better or not:

```
var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
dgvBatches.GetType().GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", flags).SetValue(dgvBatches, true);
```

<sup>1 - What a *high number* is depends on multiple factors, not just the number of Rows. You know the number of Rows is *high* when you test how the grid responds to different forms of interaction and you find it doesn't react as expected.</sup>