# Windows Forms DataGridView view gets distorted when scrolling across the fields

Tags: vb.net

Good Day,

I am facing this issue in one of the VB .Net app I have. I am populating a datagridview. When scrolling the view to left or right to see other columns, the view appears bit distorted or broken. See attached image. Wondering if there's any fix to prevent this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use `DataGridView1.Refresh()` handling the `DataGridView1.Scroll event`?

Comment: No, I haven't. I will try to add and see if that works.

Comment: @Calaf Many thanks for that. I have added this code as you advised and although there is a small flicker I am no longer getting that grey color overlap on the datagridview.


  Private Sub DataGridView1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Scroll
        Try
            DataGridView1.Refresh()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

Comment: I'm glad I was of help. I posted my suggestion as an answer, so that it is easily accessible to anyone with the same problem. I've also added a tip to avoid flickering.

Comment: Double-buffer your DataGridView. You can do that with a Custom Control or with Reflection. See the notes on the last paragraph here: [Setting the height of Rows of a DataGridView to a custom value is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67483565/7444103) or applied directly here: [Problem while scrolling merged Header Cells of a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67246419/7444103) -- Nothing helps if you're custom-drawing the Cells' content incorrectly, if you're looping Rows inside event handlers, if you use the `CellFormatting` event improperly etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rendering problem can be solved by invoking a `Refresh()` on the grid handling the `Scroll` event:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Scroll
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

To avoid flickering when scrolling, I thought it was enough to do a type check

```
If e.Type = ScrollEventType.EndScroll Then DataGridView1.Refresh()
```

However, it seems that the `EndScroll` Type is never assigned due to a bug: [DataGridView Scroll event (and ScrollEventType.EndScroll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785200/datagridview-scroll-event-and-scrolleventtype-endscroll)

Anyway, there is a solution to this problem.
You can directly handle scrollbar events to get the correct ScrollEventType: [How can I receive the "scroll box" type scroll events from a DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472389/how-can-i-receive-the-scroll-box-type-scroll-events-from-a-datagridview/767603#767603)