# Drawing a line between the drawn points

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing

I draw some points over image based on some features, then i want to connect these points together with a line

```
        List<Point> LinePoints = new List<Point>();
        LinePoints.Add(p1);
        LinePoints.Add(p2);
        LinePoints.Add(p3);
```

and in the paint event:

```
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue);
            if (LinePoints.Count > 1)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLines(p, LinePoints.ToArray());
            }
```

In the first time line is drawn between points , but in the next iteration
i will add some other points to the list `LinePoints`.
In this case the old drawn line is removed and the next one is drawn
but i don not want to remove the old lines.

**How to draw line between all new points which are added to the list `LinePoints` without remove the old lines ?**

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - _t in the next iteration
i will add some other points to the list _ Show that code! Does it also include `List<Point> LinePoints = new List<Point>();` ? You probably will want to change to a List<List<Point>>, at least if your points are not __all__ connected.. See [here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936109/how-do-i-save-a-winforms-panels-drawing-content-to-a-file/26938635#26938635)

Comment: @TaW Thanks bro ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create point lists like this:

```
List<Point> LinePoints = new List<Point>();
List<List<Point>> LinePointsSet = new List<List<Point>>();
```

Thn add sets of points:

```
LinePoints.Clear();
LinePoints.Add(p1);
LinePoints.Add(p2);
LinePoints.Add(p3);
LinePointsSet.Add(LinePoints.ToList());
```

And in the `Paint` event loop over all lists:

```
foreach (var points in LinePointsSet)
{
    if (points.Count > 1) e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Blue, points.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Thanks i just create a new list every time LinePoints=new List<Point>();then add it to the list<list<point>>
Thanks bro