# How do I change my program to end an incorrect response from continously being printed?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, counter

Im coding a Rock Paper Scissors program and eveything works completely fine except for one thing. In the line of the else condition, the one that contains the while loop `(choice != 1 || choice != 2 || choice != 3)`  with the finishing `break;` command, it only ever works when an inncorect input like 4 is entered once but not a second time.

When an incorrect input is entered the first time the program will ask for the input again but if you enter another inncorrect input it will just continously just keep printing the same printf line

`printf("Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.\n");`  and then proceed to just keep printing

`Computer choice is ROCK. Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.`

```
  while (counter != 10) {

    for (i=0;i<1;i++) {
      /* Generate a random number and restrict it to the range 1 to 3 */
      randNum = rand()%3+1;
      /*printf("A random number between 1 and 3: %d\n", randNum);*/
    }

    printf("Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.\n");

    scanf("%d", &choice);


    /* User picks an option */
    
      if ( choice == 1 ){
        printf("User choice is ROCK.\n");
      }
      else if ( choice == 2 ){
        printf("User choice is PAPER.\n");
      }
      else if ( choice == 3 ){
        printf("User choice is SCISSORS.\n");
      }  
      else {
        while (choice != 1 || choice != 2 || choice != 3) {
    
          printf("Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.\n");
          scanf("%d", &choice);
          break;
      }

    }
```

The output when I enter an incorrect input twice

```
Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.
4
Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.
4
Computer choice is ROCK.
Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.
```

I've already tried using a break command but even that doesnt fix the issue. What do I have to change in my program to fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I save a Winforms panel's drawing content to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936109/how-do-i-save-a-winforms-panels-drawing-content-to-a-file)

Comment: `choice != 1 || choice != 2` is always true.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `choice != 1 || choice != 2 || choice != 3` will *always* be true. For example (as you have noticed), if `choice` is 4, then it will *not equal* 1, so the first test will be true and, thus (as you are combining tests with a logical **OR**), the *whole* condition will also be true.

However, the condition will *also* be true when `choice` is 1. Because, although the *first* test (`choice != 1`) will then be *false*, the second test (`choice != 2`) will now be true (as 1 is *not* equal to 2). Further, there is no possible number for which all three tests (or, indeed, any two of them) can be false.

What you want, instead of the **OR** (`||`) is a logical **AND** (`&&`). Also, your `break;` statement in that loop will ensure the loop only ever runs once (it doesn't break the outer `while` loop).

```c
//...
      else {
        while (choice != 1 && choice != 2 && choice != 3) {
    
          printf("Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.\n");
          scanf("%d", &choice);
      //  break; // This will end the `while` on the first loop, for ANY input!
      }
//...
```

With this, the `while` loop will run until *any one* of the three tests evaluates to `false` (i.e. if `choice` is any one of `1`, `2` or `3`).

---

Note: The above does not *fully* explain what happens with your example input (although I'm guessing the outer `while` loop ends and code that you *haven't shown* then displays the computer's choice); to do that, we need to see a bit more code, so that it is a *minimal, compilable, reproducible example*.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reworking the logic slightly to avoid calling scanf twice.  You can do this something like this:

```
  choice = 0;
  while (choice != 1 || choice != 2 || choice != 3) 
      printf("Please choose 1 for ROCK, 2 for PAPER or 3 for SCISSORS.\n");
      scanf("%d", &choice);
    
      if ( choice == 1 ){
        printf("User choice is ROCK.\n");
      }
      else if ( choice == 2 ){
        printf("User choice is PAPER.\n");
      }
      else if ( choice == 3 ){
        printf("User choice is SCISSORS.\n");
      }  
      else {
        printf("Invalid choice.")
      }
  }
```

Comment: Note that `(choice != 1 || choice != 2 || choice != 3)` can **never** be false (see the other answer).